# Single slot finality

Tags: finality

I'm interested in having L2s/rollups connected to Solana. Interoperability between these would aim to have latency reduced to the minimum.

One challenge is time to finality. Is there a plan to move towards a single slot finality model in the future? Or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no plan currently to move single-slot finality.

That would be a huge breaking change, so to be honest, I doubt that it would happen. 32 slots for finality is baked pretty deep into the system.

If you want, you can use "confirmed" for finality in your L2 system, which means that 2/3 have voted on the block. While it's technically possible for a "confirmed" block to be rolled back, I don't think it's ever been seen in the wild.